# What is : operator

Tags: html, css, operators

I have been looking at others peoples code(html, css) and I have found this : operator several times like it is used as an if statement but I am not so sure. **So if you could clarify what is : in html and css.**

```
<b:include data='blog' name='all-head-content'/>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not a valid HTML markup.

Comment: HTML does not contain operators. HTML is a document formatting language. That is probably XML used for blogger.com https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/46995?hl=en but that's just a quick guess off a google search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That signifies that the TAG belongs to a specific taglib namespace. In this case, its the namespace designated with b.

You see this extensively in things like GSP's etc.

EDIT: Heres a link to W3schools's explanation of XML's namespaces

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp

Comment: Edited to clarify W3Schools. :)